# Elastic - supporting pagination beyond 10000

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination, size

Our index is super standard. It is flat and dumped from oracle / jdbc using logstash.

We query elastic with a pretty standard query syntax too:

```
 {
    "size": 20,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
         xxxxx:xxxxx
     }
}
```

However, this does not let us go past "from : 10000".

Apparantly, by default, only 10000 pagination items are supported. We have a business requirement to render 20 items at a time, but navigable up to the 45000th element (the entire size of our index).

Is there some setting I can tweak to support going past 10000 and to 50000?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the corresponding index-wide setting is called [`index.max_result_window`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules.html) and can be arbitrarily high.

There are caveats but I think that at ~50K they don't need to be addressed straightaway.

Comment: Thanks. I am guessing I can set this via POST API? Or does it need to be done at the index creation level?

Comment: @AllenH. that's a dynamic index-level setting that can be modified anytime.

Comment: @AllenH. Although as mentioned here, you do need to worry about Deep pagination for ~50k records. I think you should have a look at the problems it creates and alternative to the use of size and from for pagination. Check this -> https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/paginate-search-results.html